# How to add a document with a custom model in Alfresco Community?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I just created a custom model in Alfresco Share using the web interface and for some reason I can't use it when I try to create a document.

[image: Translation : Create a document thanks to a model]

I know that model works because I can edit existing documents to change their types.
Any ideas ?

I tried to activate / desactivate the Model, without getting different results.
I edited the model , restarted Alfresco server and it's the same.

Comment: I never used the UI modeler but maybe you have to setup Share to offer the new types in the dialogs? Check Jeff's excellent Tutorial [Working With Custom Content Types in Alfresco](https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html)

Comment: @HeikoRobert I tried to redo all my models following that wonderful guide but for some reason even with its examples, it doesn't show on share. I think it's linked to the fact that it doesn't create me a AMP file but a jar one...